# URL Result from QR Code Scanner only show text

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

I'm new at programming and I tried to build QR Code Scanner app. My problem is in the Scanner, I can't have the result clickable even though the QR Code contains URL link on it. It just shows a pop-up text.

Here's my code:

Scanner:

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    Button scan_btn = findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity = this;

    IntentIntegrator qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);

    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




    }


}
}
```

Can anybody fix this?

Comment: I don't see you trying something to make your result clickable. Toasts won't have clickable elements in them. You will have to make t clickable some other way. (for example setting the scanned text into a TextVIew, and making it auto-create links.)

Comment: @VladMatvienko What should I do to make it clickable and direct it to browser? I'm really sorry I'm just a newbie

Comment: it should take you ~18 seconds to google out the answer: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+textview+links+click&oq=android+textview+links+click&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7999j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @VladMatvienko I still can't figure it out where to put some answer that I search in my code sir, please help me

Comment: instead of showing result in toast set it to a TextView first. Then figure out how to make Links in TextView clickable (using link to google I have provided). If you don't know how to set text to TextView, then I'm afraid that you're missing Android basics, which you absolutely have to learn before starting.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I didn't learn android basics in the beginning, my condition right now is force me to learn specific code for QR Code Scanner, my deadline is near. I'm really sorry if you need to explain this kinda thing to me.

Comment: that is not going to work this way. If you don't want to learn - just pay somebody to do it instead of you.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I tried to learn from this too sir, is it so wrong to ask some code that I didn't know how it works and understand it? I tried to figure out too whats wrong in my code and I hope people that smarter and have way more understanding for this can tell me whats wrong

Comment: @VladMatvienko is not that I don't want to learn. I don't have time to learn it so fast. Thanks to my professor in college that tells me that my thesis need to add some app that never been teach in my whole college life. And he just gave like 1 week.